# loopback equal to date is not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

I am new to loopback. I have a date column start_date with DATE datatype.
when i try to fetch data with greater than or less than operations on start_date is working, but when i tried to fetch data equal to a date its not working:

the following is my fetching part:

Its working:

```
app.models.goals.find({where: { 
    start_date: {gt:'2016-03-31'}
  }}, function(err, res) {
});
```

Its not working:

```
app.models.goals.find({where: { 
    start_date: '2016-03-31'
  }}, function(err, res) {
});
```

Data is there in DB for 2016-03-31, but empty response. Is any syntax error.please help me to solve this.

Comment: Perhaps you need to wrap '2016-03-31' in a date constructor like `new Date('2016-03-31')`

Comment: @Freeman Lambda still its empty

Comment: you are making a query to db then you can not use like this if yo want t use the start_date.equals(your value)

Comment: @Atul Agrawal  its loopback syntax..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the syntax. I tried the same syntax in both Strongloop API Explorer and with loopback Node.JS API and found it to be working.

However, While checking these out, I noticed that when the date string doesn't have time and TZ information in it, the time portion is assumed to be 00.00.00 in the local timezone. For example, when I used the following code on my "Sandbox" model:

```
Sandbox.find({where: {myDateProp:'2016-04-2'}}, function(err, res){
    console.log('results are %j', res);
    next();
});
```

The retrieved results record contained:

```
Retreived results are [{"myStringProp":"String5","myDateProp":"2016-04-01T18:30:00.000Z","id":"56fc1dc6b9de1a6b06750b98"}]
```

Notice that my search for 2016-04-2 actually matched a record with date 2016-04-01 6:30 PM which is the GMT equivalent of 2016-04-2 00:00:00 IST.

I am guessing that this may have something to do with the behaviour that you observe. I'd recommend you to check the Date value of `start_date` of the record in the database. Then, if necessary add the time and timezone information to the filter in your code.